# Can I use Socket.io and Express withour routes for my templates?

Tags: html, node.js, express, socket.io

I think this is a really noob question, but I'd like to know if I can run a Socket.io event server in a folder and run an HTML page using that server without being in the same folder. That is becaues when you user EXPRESS you have to especify the route of the template that the server is listening. And I have seen a lot of tutorials but all of them are using routes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can set up your URLs and their corresponding routes however you like. Is there a specific code snippet you are struggling with? There is no mandatory mapping of URI paths to filesystem paths. It's just a sensible convention, but if you want the `/app/house` URI to render `public/watermelon/donkey.html`, you can do that.